# WPF animating falling textblocks

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm making a little math game in WPF and I have some "falling textblocks" that contain multiplications that you have to answer correctly before they reach the bottom of the window.

Currently it looks like this

[image: Screenshot from the game]

What I'm doing right now is that each textblock is a custom WPF control that contains a textblock to represent the expression and a textbox where user can input the answer to that expression. These are generated inside of a 40x20 grid where I'm using a `DispatcherTimer` to continiously move them down the grid until the reach the end of the grid.

There are two main problems with this approach:

1. The "effect" of falling isn't very smooth, it's very choppy, I have been able to improve the fluidity of the movement somewhat by expanding the grid downwards and decreasing the interval at which the `DispatcherTimer` ticks but it is at best a band-aid solution and I can still tell that the movement is very mechanical.
2. The other problem is closely related to the first one, whenever a textbox of these falling expressions is focused the falling becomes far far worse, it really slows to a crawl I'm guessing redrawing each and every control while having focus on a textbox is severely decreasing the performance which is causing this.

Anyhow because of this, I am seeking an alternative way of doing this, preferably it has to be easy to use and easy to integrate with my current code.

Comment: WPF has a very extensive support for animation. You can start here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a canvas and change their position inside the DispatcherTimer.

Sample mockup grabbed on a website, implementation was for dragging objects.

```
void onDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(myThumb, Canvas.GetLeft(myThumb) + e.HorizontalChange);
            Canvas.SetTop(myThumb, Canvas.GetTop(myThumb) + e.VerticalChange);
        }
```

Here is a related question: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298216/moving-any-control-in-wpf)

Here is the main draggable control article: [Here](http://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/13/wpf-draggable-objects-and-simple-shape-connectors/)

Comment: Indeed it seems canvas does work better, unfortunately I still experience the same kind of "lag" whenever a textbox is focused..

Comment: Well maybe the solution here is not smoothness but a different approach when it's focused. I suggest pausing the textbox or, when a certain textbox is focused. display a textbox on the side that's not moving and only for user input, then relay the input to that control.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use "StoryBoard" and "Animation" to handle your UserControl falling.
The built-in animations are based on a "Timer" systems but it already handles all problems like "do not post 3 changes to screen if the previous change isn't commited yet", or "abort previous position rendering if the UI Thread didn't have time to start rendering it".

So, I would generate "Storyboard"s programmatically. 
It is useful knowning that each DependencyProperty could be "animated".

See: [Using a Storyboard animation on a programatically-added control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695782/using-a-storyboard-animation-on-a-programatically-added-control)

Here is my code to animate a property which has a "Double" type:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a linear animation
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="duration"></param>
    public void CreateDoubleLinearAnimation(DependencyObject element, string name, string property, double? valueFrom, double valueTo, TimeSpan timeSpan, Storyboard sb)
    {

        // --- Animation toute bête
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
        animation.Duration = new Duration(timeSpan);
        animation.To = valueTo;
        if (valueFrom != null)
            animation.From = valueFrom.Value;
        animation.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, name);
        animation.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath(property));

        sb.Children.Add(animation);
    }
```

Example of call:

```
Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
CreateDoubleLinearAnimation(element, "myElement", "(UIElement.Opacity)", 0, 1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), sb);
```

Examples of "property" parameter:

```
(Shape.StrokeThickness)
(UIElement.Opacity)
(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(RotateTransform.Angle)
```

Best regards,

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work, the property that I want to animate isnt a direct property of the control it's an attached property indiciating the relative position of the control in relation to it's parent.